# How to insert rows to fresh table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parsing

I have a parser for my prices. I have a fresh table. It grabs prices from a website and makes SQL file that can easily be ran on phpmyadmin. And it's not made correctly because it updates the prices, but I need it to insert them.

Code:

```
<?php 
$prices = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.csgofast.com/price/all"),true);
echo "we are get ".count($prices)." actual prices\r'n";

$sql = "";
foreach($prices as $k=>$v){
    $sql .="UPDATE analyst SET current_price=\"".$v."\" WHERE market_name=\"".$k."\";";
}

file_put_contents("prices_".time().".sql", $sql, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
echo "good job\r\n";
?>
```

It basically grabs the prices from a website, and makes it update my `analyst` table with the info. All I need is that it would INSERT them, NOT update them.

How do I change it so it will make a SQL file that would INSERT them not UPDATE?

Comment: Well just changing UPDATE to INSERT doesn't work  :/

Comment: Hint: [`INSERT` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html).

Comment: *"doesn't work"* - doesn't help

Comment: did you at least try to read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change you code to:

```
<?php 

$prices = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.csgofast.com/price/all"),true);
echo "we are get ".count($prices)." actual prices\r'n";

$sql = "";
foreach($prices as $k=>$v){
    $sql .="INSERT INTO analyst (current_price, market_name) VALUES (\"".$v."\", \"".$k."\");";
}

file_put_contents("prices_".time().".sql", $sql, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
echo "good job\r\n";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`INSERT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
(column1, column2, column3,...columnN)  
VALUES
(value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

Comment: because you repeated the "," (comma):

Comment: INSERT INTO analyst (current_price, market_name) VALUES ('0.54', 'Sticker | AZR | Cologne 2015');